# How to do autocomplete and get column data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

**autoNameSearch.php**

```
<?php     
        $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
        if(!$conn)
        {
            die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
        }
         mysql_select_db("ProductDetails",$conn) or die("Could not select database");

         //           $searchTag = array(); 
        $sql = mysql_query("select shortSearch from proddetail");


        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

            $search[]= '"'.$row['shortSearch'].'"';


            }
```

**productSearch.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">-->

  <script type="text/javascript" >  var searchTags = new Array( <?php implode(',', $search)?>);   for(var i=0; i<searchTags.length;i++){
      searchTags.toString();
      document.write("contains: " +searchTags[i]+ "<br>");   }   document.write = searchTags;
    $(function(){
        searchTags  

        $("#key").autocomplete({
      source: searchTags
    });   });   </script>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="displayProducts.php?go" id="searcform" target="display">
            <div class="menubar" id="leftNavMenuBar">
                            <a href="#" class="hashAdded" style="color: #605f5d">
                    <i></i>
                    <i></i>
                    <i></i>
                    <span>choose</span></a></div><span id="bms">BMS</span><span id="marketing">MARKETING</span>
                    <input type="search" name="key" id="key" value="" class="autosearch">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="FIND">
        </form>
        </p>

    </body>
```

Comment: I want fetch data from mysql column and get that array in jquery for autocomplete... please help me ....

Comment: Just a notice: Consider stop using `mysql_` as it deprecated and start using `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your autoNameSearch.php file to something like this:

```
<?php     
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1234");
    if(!$conn)
    {
        die('Could not connect : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("ProductDetails",$conn) or die("Could not select database");

     //           $searchTag = array(); 
    $sql = mysql_query("select shortSearch from proddetail");

    $myResults = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        //$search[]= '"'.$row['shortSearch'].'"';
        array_push($myResults, $row['shortSearch']);
    }

    echo json_encode($myResults);
```

This will store your data in a PHP array and then you use the PHP json_encode function to turn that into json that autoComplete can read.

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply (*I did not see how you include the autoNameSearch.php in your script*):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function(){
    $("#key").autocomplete({ /* MAKE SURE YOUR INPUT HAS key ID TAG ON IT */
      source: "autoNameSearch.php" /* THE FILE WHERE TO GET THE DATA */
    });
  });
</script>
```

Your `autoNameSearch.php` file (I'll change it to `mysqli_*` because `mysql_*` is already [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)).

What I also notice on your provided code is that you did not print the results in your `autoNameSearch.php` file. So it should be like this:

```
<?php     

  /* ESTABLISH CONNECTION */
  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "1234", "ProductDetails");

  /* CHECK CONNECTION */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }

  if($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT shortSearch FROM proddetail")){ /* CHECK PREPARED STATEMENT */
    $stmt->execute(); /* EXECUTE QUERY */
    $stmt->bind_result($shortsearch); /* BIND THE RESULT TO THIS VARIABLE */
    while($stmt->fetch()){ /* FETCH ALL RESULTS */
      $search[] = $shortsearch; /* STORE ALL RESULTS TO THIS ARRAY VARIABLE */
    } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */
    $stmt->close();
  } /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

  echo json_encode($search); /* PRINT THE RESULT IN JSON */

?>
```